# How would I make this code work? I'm trying to figure out how to activate progress when it comes into view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not sure how to make this work

```js
let progressBar = document.querySelector(".circular-progress");
let valueContainer = document.querySelector(".value-container");

let progressValue = 0;
let progressEndValue = 65;
let speed = 50;

let progress = setInterval(() => {
    progressValue++;
    valueContainer.textContent = `${progressValue}%`;
    progressBar.style.background = `conic-gradient(
        #FBDA9D ${progressValue * 3.6}deg,
        #683279 ${progressValue * 3.6}deg
    )`;
    if (progressValue == progressEndValue) {
        clearInterval(progress);
    }

}, speed);
```

Updated to be a bit cleaner - this code works on page load, I would like to know how to activate it when it comes to view.

Comment: What do you think `document.addEventListener('scroll', ".value-container");` is doing?

Answer (score 0):

I think it says `addEventListener` requires a js method, not class selector. You can learn more on [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp)

The usage of `addEventListener` is this:

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  // Code
});
```

I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do by writing

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', ".value-container");
```

but you should do it with this syntax that written in MDN Web Docs:

```
addEventListener(type, listener)             // or
addEventListener(type, listener, options)    // or
addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture)
```

(And listener means a function)

Comment: They are likely trying to implement [event delegation like jQuery's](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler), but doing that wrong also.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). This is a build in Browser API which can determine if a element is in the viewport / visible.

In your case your code could look like this:

```js
   let options = {
      root: document.querySelector("body"),
      rootMargin: "0px",
      threshold: 1.0,
   };

   let interval;

    // this function gets called everytime the intersection status changes - so when it becomes visible and becomes hidden
    const observerCallback = (entries) => {
      // you only have one item so you can directy use index 0
      if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
        interval = setInterval(progress, speed)
      }
      else {
       // OPTIONAL: Stop the animation and reset it if it leaves the viewport
       clearInterval(interval);
       progressValue = 0;
    }

    let observer = new IntersectionObserver(observerCallback, options);

    // this tells the observer to observe your element
    observer.observe(document.querySelector(".circular-progress"));
```

Also you'll need to update your progress function. The way you define it, the interval starts as soon as the script gets executed. As soon as setInterval() gets called the interval starts.

```js
const progress = () => {
    progressValue++;
    valueContainer.textContent = `${progressValue}%`;
    progressBar.style.background = `conic-gradient(
        #FBDA9D ${progressValue * 3.6}deg,
        #683279 ${progressValue * 3.6}deg
    )`;
    if (progressValue == progressEndValue) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

}
```

Just call it in the observer callback function as seen above.

Also this line wont work:

```
element.classList.add(progress);
```

`progress` will get a numeric id assigned by the `setInterval` function, so appending the id to the elements classlist will not work as intented, because it is not a valid class. You are using the element provided by `document.querySelector`, so you are already applying the styles to the object in the DOM. (also `element` is not defined - at least in the snippet you provided)